Mixed Up About Multiple Projects in a Solution With multiple main()s
I have a Main Project with lots of files including a main() which drives everything.
I have a stand-alone Parser Project with a main(), but its other files are intended to be used by the Main Project. This main() is just used for testing/working-on this project by itself.
I have a second Parser project with a main() that needs files from the Main Project and has files needed by the main project. The main() is used for testing/working on this project by itself.
I have a fourth project that consists solely of unit tests withing a testing Framework. It requires files from the other three projects.
The two Parser projects seemed like logically simple things, needed by the Main Project, but that could be built and worked on apart from the Main project.
I am lost on a convenient way to structure my solution to avoid clashes with multiple mains.
I like being able to test the two Parser Projects separately instead of having one big main that knows how to do everything.
I've tried excluding the main .obj files in the project property pages, but that only seems to care about libraries.
The unit tests require all the projects to be built first, guaranteeing clashes.
This really doesn't feel like a far-fetched example...what is the point of multiple projects in a solution if they cant co-exist and interact?

How are they supposed to interact normally? Are you compiling them all to exes? The typical way is to only have one main, and to use actual unit tests using a framework, not using multiple mains ...

Each project produces one executable (or DLL).  Each project should include the source files it needs.  They don't have to interact.

The individual projects should not share the source files that have the int main() meaning have at most 1 main implementation per project.

Let's say one project is a tool that processes files for the main project and needs files from the main project. The tool grows as the main project grows. Am I not able to keep that in the same solution just because it has its own executable?

Maybe you want to have a static library that has the shared functionality between the 2 projects.

You can have as many .exe projects and as many .lib projects as you want in the same solution file. At work I typically have 20 or so libraries and 5 or so executables on a typical solution of 200k lines of code.

drescherjm - I am currently in the process of converting the solution to various .lib projects with several executable projects to see how that works out for me...might take a bit lol.

drescherjm - I still think Visual Studio could be smart enough to avoid linking multiple main()s, or be smarter about where to store the main.objs. Perhaps it just requires manipulating the Properties pages better than I have. Anyhow, the .libs and .exes have been working for me, so if you post an answer, I will select it. Thanks!

Only header files and definitions are required for each project. There is no need for interaction between projects.
CPP files will be compiled to .obj.
Hello.h ,Hello.cpp -> Hello.obj

You can add obj as dependencies to your test project. It's like using library.
Add obj folder path properties -> linker -> general -> Additional Library Directories
Add obj file properties -> linker -> input -> Additional Dependencies.
If you have multiple files in your project for testing, consider creating a static library for the shared code.
In addition， there is project type shared item project.

I couldn't see how the shared item project could help me here, but thanks for mentioning it!

Usage of shared item project:  put the shared header file and cpp files in the shared item project. In the exe project that #include the header files, right-click project -> add -> reference -> shared projects. In this way, you don't need to build it into static library.
